# passing an object (self) into extension

Tags: swift, filter, extension-methods

I'm experimenting with writing Swifts `.filter` function and have run into some confusion. I'm essentially trying to modify this function:

```
func anotherFilter<T>(elements: [T], predicate: (T) -> Bool) -> [T] {
    var filteredArray = [T]()
    for element in elements {
        if predicate(element) {
            filteredArray += [element]
        }
    }
    return filteredArray
}
```

Into an extension:

```
extension Array {
    func anotherFilter<T>(elements: [T], predicate: (T) -> Bool) -> [T] {
        var filteredArray = [T]()
        for element in elements {
            if predicate(element) {
                filteredArray += [element]
            }
        }
        return filteredArray
    }
}
```

Of course this version of the extension works but it requires that you pass the object in which doesn't make sense:

```
self.coords.anotherFilter (coords) { self.someOperation(coords, op: $0) }
```

**What I've Tried**

Obviously, what I'd like to achieve is something like this:

```
extension Array {

    func anotherFilter <T>(predicate: (T) -> Bool) -> [T] {
        var filteredArray = [T]()
        for item in self {
            if predicate(item) {
                filteredArray.append(item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this returns an error:

> Cannot invoke 'predicate' with an argument list of type '(Element)'

### Question

How do I pass the object (in this case coords) into my extension without parameterizing it? Deeper explanations are most welcome.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, i'll take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array already has a placeholder type for its elements: `Element`. Your generic parameter `T` is exactly that placeholder type, so you can just use `Element`:

```
extension Array {
    func anotherFilter(predicate: (Element) -> Bool) -> [Element] {
        var filteredArray = [Element]()
        for item in self where predicate(item) {
            filteredArray.append(item)
        }
        return filteredArray
    }
}
```

Comment: I just arrived at this a moment ago. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

It requires a "self" if the object is not instantiated. I guess it would need to be a static method instead.

```
static func anotherFilter<T>(elements: [T], predicate: (T) -> Bool) -> [T]
```

Comment: I'm trying to do away with passing elements: [T] into my extension.